# How can I redirect text to then write at specified line number?

Tags: io-redirection

Is it possible to redirect a text string to a "in-argument specified" line instead of at the latter of a file? Or a combination of commands/and or arguments, subshells if this isn't possible with redirection.

Comment: At least with GNU sed, you can **r**ead `/dev/stdin` and queue it to be written to a given file after a given address... perhaps if you could give a more concrete example of what you want to do?

Answer (score 0):

With  GNU `awk`:

```
text_string='some arbitrary
text'
line_number=12
file=/some/file

STRING="$text_string" gawk -i /usr/share/awk/inplace.awk -v n="$line_number" -e '
  NR == n {print ENVIRON["STRING"]}
  {print}' -E /dev/null "$file"
```

Same with `perl`:

```
perl -spi -e '$_ = "$string\n$_" if $. == $n
  ' -- -string="$text_string" -n="$line_number" -- "$file"
```

Those edit the file in-place (actually replace it with an edited copy).

The gawk variant doesn't work for a file called `-`. To edit the file called `-` in the current directory, use `./-` instead.

Also, **do not use `-i inplace`** as `gawk` tries to load the `inplace` extension (as `inplace` or `inplace.awk`) from the current working directory first, where someone could have planted malware. The path of the `inplace` extension supplied with `gawk` may vary with the system, see the output of `gawk 'BEGIN{print ENVIRON["AWKPATH"]}'`